# Trouble Installing web3 for node

Tags: web3js

I'm attempting to install web3 for node on ubuntu but it seems there is an issue with the url within the installation script.

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ npm -v

5.0.3

osboxes@osboxes:~$ node -v

v8.1.0

osboxes@osboxes:~$ npm install web3

npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/osboxes/.npm/_logs/2017-06-24T02_20_54_548Z-debug.log

osboxes@osboxes:~$
```

---

Inside the log is the following:

```
26 silly resolveWithNewModule xmlhttprequest@1.8.0 checking installable status
27 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for bignumber.js@git+https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git#94d7146671b9719e00a09c29b01a691bc85048c2 exited with error code: 128
28 verbose stack Error: exited with error code: 128
28 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.onexit (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:39:36)
28 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
28 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
28 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is being tracked here, there is a PR in progress to address it: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/904